# Show that for any integrable function...

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Show that for any integrable function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ we have   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{n}^{n+1}f(x) dx = 0$$

What’s the way to solve it. Can I use Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem? Or I have to use the idea that the step functions are dense in $L^{1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx<\infty$ and by monotone convergence theorem, $\int_{0}^{n}|f(x)|dx\uparrow\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx$. Now we use the simple Cauchy criterion:

\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{0}^{m}|f(x)|dx-\int_{0}^{n}|f(x)|dx\right|<\varepsilon
\end{align*}
for $m,n\geq N$. Now pick $m=n+1$ and we have
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{n}^{n+1}f(x)dx\right|\leq\int_{n}^{n+1}|f(x)|dx<\varepsilon,\quad n\geq N.
\end{align*}

Comment: Does  Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem works ?

Comment: In some sense. You may notice that $\chi_{[n,n+1]}(x)f(x)\rightarrow 0$ pointwise as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Now you see that $|\chi_{[n,n+1]}(x)f(x)|\leq|f(x)|$ and so Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem works. Personally I think this is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f \in L^1$,
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|  \ dx &= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\int_n^{n+1}|f(x)| \ dx  < \infty
\end{align*}
$$
Since the series converges, we must have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_n^{n+1}|f(x)|  = 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Use Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence theorem for $f_n = f\cdot1_{[n,n+1]}$ Indeed $f_n\to 0$ pointwise and $|f_n(x)|\le |f(x)|$ with $\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x)|dx<\infty$, so: $$\int_n^{n+1}f(x)\,dx=\int_\mathbb{R} f_n(x)\ dx\to \int_\mathbb{R} 0\,dx=0$$